# Using the Windows command line to turn of DNS registration for specific NICs

Tags: networking, dns, vmware-workstation

Systems with VMware Workstation installed have two virtual NICs, identified by their name (usually), which looks like `VMware Network Adapter <VNet name>`. I am having issues remotely connecting to the hosts because the default IP range for the VMware VNets exists as VLANs in our enterprise networks. When the host registers its NICs with the DNS servers, the VMware NICs are included.

When another client on the network then attempts to communicate with the host, it may attempt to do so using the VMware IP range, which doesn't work.

So I would like to develop a script (Windows CMD or PowerShell) that would turn off the setting that configures the virtual NICs to register with DNS.

Note: I realize that if I were to change the IP address ranges of the virtual network cards entirely, this issue may resolve itself. However, this is in a lab environment where VMware is deployed silently. Thus, it seems easier to disable DNS registration than to modify the IP ranges.

Comment: I think the answer's found in this How To on Spiceworks.com: https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/138214-how-to-remove-nic-dns-registration-with-powershell

Answer (score 0):

Use the VMware Network Editor (Start, scroll down for VMware, open the menu folder. open Network Editor as Administrator and change the NAT range to a range you are not using. Make sure your guest machines have been shut down first and then close out and restart the host computer